# LaTeX + Atom configuration - I have downloaded all the packages but it just seems to not compile correctly

Tags: compiling, distributions, atom

[image: The error message that was displayed when I tried running the script]

[image][image]
[image]

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
 \title{Introduction to \LaTeX{}}
\author{Author's Name} 
\maketitle \begin{abstract}
The abstract text goes here. \end{abstract} 
\section{Introduction} Here is the text of your introduction. 
 \begin{equation} \label{simple_equation} \alpha = \sqrt{ \beta } 
\end{equation} \subsection{Subsection Heading Here} Write your 
subsection text here. \section{Conclusion} Write your conclusion 
here. \end{document}
```

I just want to be able to compile LaTeX files without having that error messages. I have downloaded all the necessary packages.

P.S. = I am still a beginner in programming and setting up environments in different IDE's so forgive me if I misconstrue what you are saying.

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE. Could you include include the script inline in this page? So that we can cut-copy and test it?

Comment: @Raaja I am confused. What is the script inline exactly? Sorry. I know, I am just a beginner. I have added some photos to the original post.

Comment: Simply put, you can copy-paste your script (the one you attached as a screenshot) into this page so that we could copy them and test it. Currently, your script is shown in the image and it cannot be tested.

Comment: Your second picture (also the bottom of the first) has the error `loo.tex28 File 'myfigure' not found` - the first part indicates line 28 of the file loo.tex, which seems to be `\section{Conclusion}`.  The next error indicates that it is trying to compile test.tex.  So I'm confused about what file you're trying to compile.  Open a Windows command prompt, and in that directory type `pdflatex loo`.  What do you get?

Comment: @HusseinAl-Odwan You can modify your question by clicking on the "edit" link at the bottom left.

Comment: @HusseinAl-Odwan What packages are you talking about? Atom's or LaTeX's?

Comment: @Teepeemm I just attached what I get in the original post. I am trying to compile test.tex.

Comment: In that case, you want to type `pdflatex test`.

Comment: @Teepeemm still not working. I tried to compile but it gives me an error message. Going to update the original post with what it shows me.