# LaTeX + Atom configuration: make it latex work on it

Tags: pdftex, atom

[image]

I have been trying to compile it into a pdf but nothing has been working. I am new to this so please bear with me!

This is the original script -

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
a small \LaTeX document

later on it wont be working!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Only with your image, I personally, I absolutely do not see the very small fonts. You could not, please, add a complete tex code, i.e. a minimal working example and the compilation error(s).  So we can help you better.

Comment: The error reading a file seems to be on line 38. But you don’t even show line 38. What are we to do?

Comment: @HerbSchulz there is no line 38 … I am a beginner at this. Please bear with me. I updated the original post.

Comment: @HusseinAl-Odwan Excuse me, but where are the packages that you use? `\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
a small \LaTeX \, document

later on it wont be working!

\end{document}`. Try this that works: `LaTeX` is a command.

Comment: @sebastiano im confused. What do you mean? How do I fix this?

Comment: @HusseinAl-Odwan There's nothing to fix. You should read a LaTeX guide or manual - that's my advice. You should simply copy my last comment code and try.  You will see that everything will work correctly.

Comment: Your last comment is wrong. Can you write it again? Apologies, I am just new to this. @sebastiano

Comment: @HusseinAl-Odwan I have added an answer.

Comment: Do you have test1.pdf open in some reader (es. Acrobat)? Please close it and retry!

Comment: How is this question different from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505713/latex-atom-configuration-i-have-downloaded-all-the-packages-but-it-just-seem

Comment: Well, what do you mean with "Atom" or "Atom configuration"? Please explain better in your question! Is this a special computer? Please explain used OS and installed TeX distribution.